# Merging two dataframes with same column names but different number of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, append

I have two pandas dataframes

```
df1 = DataFrame([[0,123,321],[0,1543,432]], columns=['A', 'B','C'])
df2 = DataFrame([[1,124],[1,1544]], columns=['A', 'C'])
```

I want to merge these so that the new dataframe would look like below

```
A     |    B      |   C
0         123        321
0         1543       432
1         null       124
1         null       1544
```

I have tried using append and concat but nothing seems to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: adding the code-snippets for your failed attempts with append & concat will help to resolve specific errors

Answer (score 11):

Concatenate the dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
   A     B     C
0  0   123   321
1  0  1543   432
0  1   NaN   124
1  1   NaN  1544
```

Comment: Thanks this does the trick. I am marking this as answer because it also caters to empty dataframes. Append method doesn't work with empty dataframes.

Answer (score 8):

from [doc-ref](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) ref
try: `df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)`

#### sample output:

```
    A     B     C
 0  0   123   321
 1  0  1543   432
 2  1   NaN   124
 3  1   NaN  1544
```